# Bind all missing frontends rules to custom error pages

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik, custom-error-pages

I want to bind every missing frontends to a custom 404 page. I prepared a server to handle the request but I don't know how to configure Traefik to use this page. In the documentation example there is a frontend website, what I don't have.

For exemple:

https://existing-frontend.example.org should work as usual

but

https://not-existing-frontend.example.org should use 404 custom page on other server.

Could you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at the moment, but feel free to [open a feature request](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md).

Comment: Thank for the quick answer !

Comment: I opened an issue here https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4218